# Comment dire « DSL » en français?

Tags: traduction, informatique

J'ai récemment vu [cette page Web](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro-fr.html) et j'ai vu que « DSL » est utilisé avec la même orthographe qu'en anglais. « DSL » (*domain specific language* en anglais) est une terme technique en informatique. Donc, je voudrais savoir si cette page est correcte. J'ai pensé qu'on utiliserait au moins un ordre de mots différent, puisque l'ordre des adjectifs est différent en français, mais je ne sais pas si, avec des termes techniques, on utilise la même abréviation quand on traduit un mot, pour la clarté.

Comment: Bienvenue sur FL&U! J'ai révisé ta question pour y corriger quelques trucs et la rendre un peu plus concise. S'il y a un problème, fais-nous signe, ou clique sur « edit » pour modifier ta question!

Comment: *Langage spécifique au domaine*, qui serait la traduction littérale, a des initiales évoquant autre chose que le procédé en question...

Comment: J'avoue faire l'anglicisme quand je parle de DSL :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dans le cadre de Sinatra, il faudrait parler de "[langage dédié](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_d%C3%A9di%C3%A9)" bien que *DSL* puisse être compris par les personnes qui liraient la page.

De manière générale, *DSL* est utilisé en français plutôt pour parler de *Digital Subscriber Line* comme dans ADSL ou SDSL.